# Have Win8 and Win7 different CultureInfo on the same culture? (different dateSeparator)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, cultureinfo, culture

I'm moving all my info and projects from Win7 to Win8 when suddenly an unexpected error appears with the `datepicker` `Uncaught Unexpected literal at position 2`.

I set the CurrentCulture to `es-VE` like this:
`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("es-VE")`

On my debugging process I found that the problem is my `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat`

Win7 sets it like this:
[image]

Win8 sets it like this:
[image]

As you can see the `dateSeparator` changes and that's throwing the `Javascript` exception cause its expecting dd/mm/yyyy instead of dd-mm-yyyy

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Is it a bug from Microsoft?

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Update:
Control Panel, settings are the same on both machines.

[image]

Comment: can you check the control panel?

Comment: @DanielA.White its the same on both machines, it would not matter if I'm forcing the setting.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'll will be nice to know the reason...

Comment: please share your javascript side. maybe something can be improved.

Comment: Anytime you pass a date as a string to JavaScript, you should use a [custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the [culture specific ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx). Then things are less likely to break due to culture settings. When you show dates to users, use culture settings. When you're passing dates in code, use invariant culture and/or custom format.

Comment: @DanielA.White i think the problem is on the backend not on the javascript, I found the error thanks to the JS, yes it can be fixed if I do some fixes, but I think its not the idea to touch the JS.

Comment: @mason this is a web service, today is consumed by a JS, tomorrow could be something else. I think the problem should be fixed on the backend. I agree by using a `custom format specifier`, by why if I use the same culture `es-VE` I got different date separator values?

Comment: There have been a lot of changes in Venezuela, Microsoft just follows whatever direction the political wind is blowing.  Your Control Panel view is for your local culture, you'd have to change the machine's locale to see the overrides that are effective for es-VE.  Use superuser.com to ask questions about this.

Comment: @HansPassant ok, I thought it was more of a related question to the Framework instead of the OS. But you practically answer my question about the `CultureInfo` class due to the political changes in Venezuela, the fact is that all the dates are still being shown as `dd/MM/yyyy` (including newspapers and government web pages) idk where did Microsoft found info about that change, but I guess they have thier sources... Thx

Answer (score 0):

We make changes to data as we are made aware of better data that is available. You should never assume that the data will be the same. Best practice then is to ensure that any persisted data  is stored or transferred using a standard format (ISO 8601 for dates). Localized data should be ephemeral.

By the way, the control panel settings only allow overrides for the user locale but if the user locale happens to be the culture that in question, you can make changes (one more reason why applications should not make assumptions about the data not changing).